# Input data values in each neuron in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, input, neural-network, training-data

I want to know how a dataset is fed to a neural network. Suppose I have a weather dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nicolausboby/weathernominal). The features of the dataset are *outlook, temperature, humidity, windy*. The class attribute is *play*. As per the neural network, each input node of the neural network represents one feature. Something like that,

[image]

If the data of the dataset are following

```
outlook    Temperature   Humidity    windy   play
Sunny       hot          high        false   no
Sunny       hot          high        True    no
overcast    hot          high        false   yes
rainy       mild         high        false   yes
rainy       cool        normal       false   yes
```

I would like to know what values should replace the **?** in the picture? I am confused between two inputs

**1st input**

[image]

**2nd input**

[image]

I think the input should be like the *1st input* picture. For me **2nd input** picture has no sense. However, somewhere on web, I read that the input array of each neuron should be row-wise input.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "row wise" means is that your data

```
outlook    Temperature   Humidity    windy   play
Sunny       hot          high        false   no
Sunny       hot          high        True    no
overcast    hot          high        false   yes
rainy       mild         high        false   yes
rainy       cool        normal       false   yes
```

should be fed **row by row**

so, you would get on first row

```
outlook=Sunny, Temperature=hot, Humidity=high, windy=false, play=no
```

each of these key=value assignments is a value for one "neuron" (note, that in reality neurons are not really able to process a string, so you will need some form of encoding, e.g. one hot encoding, which will change the effective number of neurons)

and so on and so forth.

You don't really "feed dataset in", in practise we do often use batching, where many rows are processed in parallel, but this is just an **implementational efficiency trick for heavily optimised vectorised computation**, but for pure understanding you should just ignore its existence, as it is an independent thing.

Comment: `each of these is a value for one "neuron"` - I could not understand this. If each row is for one neuron then if I have 300 instances I need 300 input neurons to train the neural network, however, in reality, the number of input neurons is proportional to the number of features.

Comment: I meant each "equality" is one neuron, not row

Comment: Can you please let me know for the current dataset which neuron received which values? I mean what should 1st neuron (outlook) , 2nd neuron(temperature) , 3rd and 4th neuron's input values?

Comment: @Encipher This is off-topic in Stack Overflow, do not ask such questions here.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Can you please let me know which StackOverflow community perfect for this question?

Comment: @Encipher Probably ai.stackexchange.com